# Privacy on a VPN Running on a VPS?

Tags: vpn, privacy, vps

What with the recent changes in U.S. law going forward regarding browsing histories a lot of people are talking about VPNs. Is there any privacy benefit to establishing a VPN on a VPS at Amazon or Digital Ocean, or would their ISP just track/sell your data at that point? Would that provide less anonymity than a commercial VPN (because less users), but more security (because you can trust yourself not to log/sell your own traffic)? What about if you let a couple dozen of your friends and family use it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely a benefit, as your ISP can't track the information at that point (Amazon could, but because of the nature of VPS's, I'd imagine this information would not be considered valuable in tracking you for ad purposes).  Having friends and family could help somewhat here.  [ But consider using TOR and running an exit node instead - that would provide more benefit and more entropy, at the cost of slower speeds ]

It could provide less anonymity, because you would have a static IP address which would uniquely identify your traffic, rather then aggregated traffic.

A VPN on your own VPS might or might not provide better security, depending on the logging of your VPN provider and their jurisdiction.  [ I have no reason to believe they WOULD do it, but Amazon could theoretically take a snapshot of your VM, get your private keys and decrypt your traffic - at the behest of a 3 letter agency for example, while a dedicated provider may or may not be willing to withstand that pressure - different jurisdictions, credibility etc (think Lavabit) ]